# Как сделать фон из точек на css?

Tags: css, css3, svg

Как сделать на css такой фон из точек?

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(https://sport.mail.ru/img/_main/subnav.png)
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: И так через CSS фон установлен.

Comment: Я немного подредактировал заголовок, но возможно он не очень хорошо раскрывает суть, поэтому можете его улучшить. Предыдущий заголовок "Как сделать такой фон…" довольно безлик, так как поисковики не индексируют картинки. [Обсуждение этой темы на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5298/220571).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Градиент:

```css
.dotted {
  padding: 2.25em 1.6875em;
  background-image: -webkit-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -moz-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: -ms-repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  background-image: repeating-radial-gradient(center center, rgba(0,0,0,.2), rgba(0,0,0,.2) 1px, transparent 1px, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-size: 3px 3px;
  -moz-background-size: 3px 3px;
  background-size: 3px 3px;
  
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dotted"></div>
```

Comment: Не очень похоже на исходный вариант, так как там массив точек. 
Я тоже пытался градиентами, но похоже это невозможно (разве что пытаться цветом фона сделать саму сетку, но если фон будет картинкой, то это не будет работать).

Answer (score 14):

Вариант с *SVG*

```css
.bg {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="3" height="3"><circle r="1" fill="%23888" /></svg>') repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: Только это будет работать только в Chrome (именно в таком виде), надо эту SVG заэскейпить и убрать `utf8`. Либо просто вынести в отдельный файл

Answer (score 10):

Я пытался самостоятельно сделать такой фон следующим образом, однако у меня не совсем то получилось:

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: radial-gradient(#000 5%, transparent 20%) 0 0, radial-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.1) 1%, transparent 1%) 50px 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-size: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

### SVG pattern

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
<defs>
<pattern id="patt"
             x="0" y="0" width="4" height="4"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
            <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="1" fill="grey" opacity="0.2"  />
</pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#patt);" />
</svg>
```

**Black pattern**

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
<defs>
<pattern id="patt"
             x="0" y="0" width="3" height="3"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
            
           <g>  
           <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="3" fill="black"  />
     <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="1" fill="white"  />
     
     </g>
</pattern>
</defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#patt);" />
</svg>
```